# How to use subfolders in a command handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make command sub folders but my bot doesn't read commands inside the folders. There is no error.

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = (client) => {
  client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
  const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands')

  const commands = [];
  for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of command_files) {
      const command = require(`../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
      client.commands.set(command.name, command);  
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adapt your `readdirSync` arguments

```
const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./commands/' + folder);
```

This will give you all your files. Then you need to:

```
for (const file of command_files) {
    const command = require('./commands/' + folder + '/' + file);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you still need to storage your `commands` on `array`? You're already using a `collection`.

```
module.exports = (client) => {
    
    client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
    const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands')

    for (const folder of commandFolders) {
        const command_files = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
        for (const file of command_files) {
            const command = require(`../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        }
    }
}

//your folders should read with readdirSync too then find all of your filtered file.endsWith('.js')
```

Comment: And if this line `const command = require(\`../commands/${folder}/${file}\`);` gaves you an error, just remove 1 `.` on `\`../commands/${folder}/${file}\``